# Retrieve the size of the virtual display area using Windows GDI

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gdi

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490(v=vs.85).aspx):

> *If there are multiple monitors on the system, calling CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL) will create a DC covering all the monitors.*

However, when I attempt to employ this, I'm not getting the expected results:

```
HDC hDisplay = CreateDCA("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
int displayX = GetDeviceCaps(hDisplay, HORZRES);
int displayY = GetDeviceCaps(hDisplay, VERTRES);

DeleteDC(hDisplay);
```

In this case, the values of `displayX` and `displayY` are in fact the dimensions of only one of the two monitors on the desktop.

Comment: The DC covers all the monitors, but the caps refer to the primary monitor. You want `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)` and `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: If you would like to make that an answer, I'll flag it as answered.